# AWS batch - how to limit number of concurrent jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am looking for a way to limit the number of batch jobs that are running by holding the remaining jobs in the queue. Is it possible with aws batch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Limiting the [maximum number of vcpus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environment_parameters.html#compute_environment_compute_resources) of the managed compute environment the queue is tied to will effectively limit the number of batch jobs running concurrently on that queue.

However, this comes with the caveat that, if you have other queues sharing this compute environment, they would also be limited accordingly. Moreover, if you have multiple compute environments associated with that queue you are attempting to limit, Batch will eventually begin scheduling jobs on the secondary compute environments if there are enough jobs waiting in the `RUNNABLE` state.