# Using AWS Glue to Create a Table and move the dataset

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I've never used AWS Glue however believe it will deliver what I want and am after some advice. I have a monthly CSV data upload that I push to S3 that has a staging Athena table (all strings) associated to it. I want Glue to perform a Create Table As (with all necessary convert/cast) against this dataset in Parquet format, and then move that dataset from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket, so the primary Athena Table can access the data.

As stated, never used Glue before, and want a starter for 10, so I don't go down rabbit holes.

I currently perform all these steps manually, so want to understand how to use Glue to automate my manual tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use AWS Glue ETL jobs to do exactly what you described. However, it doesn't perform `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` [queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html), instead it does it with ETL jobs based on spark. Here is [github repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-data-analytics/tree/master/Lab3) that describes such process in quite detailed way and here is more of official AWS documentation on [ETL programming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming.html) based on AWS Glue service. After the initial setup, you can define some trigger events/scheduling to run your Glue ETL jobs automatically.

However, one thing to remember is [cost](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/) of using AWS Glue services. Since it is based on execution time, sometimes it is not that trivial to forecast the final cost. For the workflow you described, performing `CTAS` queries with Athena would work just fine to transform your data and write it into a different s3 bucket. In this case you would know exactly price since it depends on the size of your data. Then you can use AWS API to do some manipulation with metadata catalog, so that new information would be accessible and in once place.

Since you are new to AWS Glue ETL jobs, I would suggest to stick with `CTAS` queries for simple tasks (although you can come up with quite complicated queries) and look into an open source project [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) for automation/scheduling and orchestration. This is the approach the I am using for tasks similar to yours. Airflow is easy to setup on both local and remote machines, has reach CLI and GUI for task monitoring, abstracts away all scheduling and retrying logic. It even has [hooks](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_hook/index.html) to interact with AWS services. Hell, Airflow even provides you with a [dedicated operator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/aws_athena_operator/index.html) for sending queries to Athena. I wrote a little bit more about this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313151/6147064).